# in_array "or" operator in parameters

Tags: php

Today, while I read the doc, I've seen somewhere something looking like this `in_array('value1' || 'value2', $my_array)`, so I tried, for science. And it works! Just why? How it really works behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = array(2, 3, 4);

var_dump('value1' || 'value2');
var_dump(in_array('value1' || 'value2', $array));
```

Its not so unusual.

`'value1' || 'value2'` is `true` by weak equality.

`array(2, 3, 4)` contains values that are also `true` by weak equality.

So this proves that `in_array` performs a weak comparison.  Thanks, I'll have to bare that in mind, since I use that function all of the time.

In Javascript `'value1' || 'value2'` would return `value1`, because in this context it is a "null coalescing operator".

The PHP equivalent is `'value1' ?: 'value2'` to compare the condition against a boolean, or `'value1' ?? 'value2'` for null coalescing in PHP 7.  I'm going to assume that code was a misunderstanding the language because it doesn't look useful or even make sense.

Comment: so `'value1' || 'value2'` will always be true since string is evaluate to be true in boolean??

Comment: Since they are constant strings yes.  If they were both empty strings, it would return `false`.

Comment: `in_array` has a third paramater to enable strict comparisons